# How do you bind bootstrap table searchbox to html input box?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap table which pulls in data from a php file which generates JSON, I have use the data-search="true" attribute in the table, I want to be able to search the table using a normal HTML input box so as I type it shows me relevant rows on the table, is this possible? I want to be able to do this so the table shows me if the item already exists in the table before I click submit on the form which contains the HTML input box.

Comment: It really very unclear to me.

Comment: If it helps, I am using this: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/